# 403 forbidden response when changing color of event in subscribed calendar

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am trying to change the color of a Google calendar event based on it's location.
The events i want to change are part of a synced calendar with a webcal link. I cannot change the color of each event individually but i can set the calendar's color.

The following code allowed me to change the color of individual events for another non-synced calendar (that i created myself) but for the synced calendar i get the error `403: Forbidden`.
`HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/CALENDAR_ID/events/EVENT_ID?alt=json returned "Forbidden">`

```py
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secret.json", scopes=scopes)
credentials = flow.run_console()

service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)


calId = "my_calendar_id"
calendar = service.events().list(calendarId=calId).execute()


keyword = "my_location_keyword"
for event in calendar['items']: 
# I navigate through each event of the specified calendar
    if 'location' in event and event['location'].find(keyword): 
    # if the location exists and contains the keyword, then i change the color
        service.events().patch(calendarId=calId, eventId=event['id'], body={"colorId":10}).execute()
```

Is there a way to change the color without triggering a forbidden error ? It seems to me that the color should not be protected by authorizations ...

I thought about copying the calendar into another one that i have write access to, and change the color on the new one, but this seems a bit overkill. Any better idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The `Code: 403  Message: Forbidden` error indicates that the account that is trying to edit the calendar event does not have edit access to the calendar. You must change this in the calendar share settings.*

#### More Information:

There are four options for sharing calendars with individuals, as can be seen in the Calendar UI:

[image]

Unless the individual has `Make changes to events` or `Make changes and manage sharing` access to the calendar, then this `Forbidden` response will be received.

#### Note:

As per the documentation on [handling Calendar API errors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_forbidden_for_non-organizer):

> #### 403: Forbidden for non-organizer
>
> The event update request is attempting to set one of the shared event properties in a copy that isn't the organizer's. Shared properties (for example, `guestsCanInviteOthers`, `guestsCanModify`, or `guestsCanSeeOtherGuests`) can only be set by the organizer.

While this error's details appear to be different than the much simpler `403: Forbidden` error you describe, this could be due to an API change. If you attempt to change one of the properties specified here (`guestsCanModify`, for example), without the aforementioned calendar sharing settings, then the same, simpler 403 error is returned:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

It is therefore recommended that you check the sharing settings for the calendar, as `colorId` can not be edited by a user that is not the organiser without this set correctly.

#### References:

- [Handle API Errors | Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors)
- [Sharing and Attendees - Inviting Attendees to Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing#inviting_attendees_to_events)